# Flooring timestamp to second

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
select current_timestamp(6),    current_timestamp(0)
----------------------------------------------------
2012-02-22 16:03:45.988418+13 | 2012-02-22 16:03:46+13
           -------^                   ------------^ (date from the future)
```

This query can easily return the timestamp from the future for the second column because of `current_timestamp(0)` is rounding "mathematically". This could lead to some unexpected errors, just because the retrieved time is from the future up to 0.5s.

So my question is - what is the simplest way to round `current_timestamp(6)` to the nearest second down?

PS: I know the solution with converting to seconds and back

PPS: The result should be a timestamp type, not a string

**UPD**:

Found a solution

```
select current_timestamp(6), current_timestamp(0)::abstime
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select current_timestamp(6),    date_trunc('second', current_timestamp(6))
```