# How to remove the tail from timestamp field?

Tags: postgresql

I have a `TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE` field

when I do:

```
select datex
from A
```

it shows me `datex` as: `2015-09-16 10:59:59.073629`

how do I modify it to be `2015-09-16 10:59:59`?

I don't need the tail after the seconds.

I read this http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html but coldn't find a match.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Flooring timestamp to second](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9388489/flooring-timestamp-to-second)

Answer (score 1):

You can either configure your SQL client tool to not show fractional seconds, or you can use the `to_char()` method to format the output:

```
select to_char(datex, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as datex
from A;
```

See the manual for details on the format string. This is documented in the chapter "Data Type Formatting Functions":
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

try:
`SELECT date_trunc('second', datex);`

The function date_trunc is similar to the trunc function for numbers.